# $dx$ as covector vs placeholder for integral

Tags: differential-forms

When we integrate form, we feed in the tangent vector of the curve which maybe written as:

$$ \tau= \gamma'(t) dt$$

If we had a one form integral $\int dx$ if were to feed the above into the integral:

$$ \int_{\gamma} dx = \int_{t} dx(\gamma'(t) dt) = \int_t dt dx(\gamma'(t) )$$

Now, $dx(\gamma'(t) )$ is a number but is $dt$ again a one form or not? How do we differentiate between place holder for integration variable and one form?

Hopefully my question is clear. I was not sure how to best frame this

Comment: The main point is, if $\gamma$ is a path into the domain of $x$, the tangent at $\gamma(t)$ is $\gamma'(t)$ (N.B. no "$dt$"); the one-form $dx$ transforms by $\gamma^*(dx)(t) = (x \circ \gamma)'(t)\, dt$.

Comment: Is that the pushforward map? @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: That's the pullback.